# File system stats

Tags: c, disk-access

I use the following code to find the disk usage of my `/`

```
int main()
{
    struct statfs *stat;
    statfs64("/tmp",stat);
    perror("");
    printf("%lu \n",stat->f_bfree*stat->f_bsize);
    return 0;
}
```

The perror keeps on printing "Bad Address" and a random number for size.

`Bad address`

`3264987920`

PS:I tried `sudo ./a.out`,`statfs("a.out",stat)`

What may be the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've declared a pointer to a `statfs` struct but don't actually have space allocated for such a struct. The pointer points off into nowhereland. It's uninitialized, it doesn't point anywhere legal.

```
struct statfs stat;

if (statfs64("/tmp", &stat) == -1) {
    perror("statfs64");
}
else {
    printf("%lu\n", stat.f_bfree * stat.f_bsize);
}
```

Comment: Thanks:) that worked :)I would like to add that `statfs64` may trigger a segmentation fault,which can be removed by using `statfs` instead

Comment: @RajeevS Right. `statfs()` and `struct statfs` should be used together, and `statfs64()` and `struct statfs64` as well. The use of the latter is deprecated; they are used instead of `statfs()` if the correct symbols are defined.

Answer (score 0):

You have used statfs *stat with no memory allocation hence wild pointer usage it may point to anywhere ( illegal memory address)
Either Initialise it with valid memory or use variable and pass its reference.

Comment: You are saying the same as [John said 7 1/2 hours before you...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16050052/296974)